# Why does the Aramaic Bible in Plain English put "The old is sweet"?

Tags: word-study

**Luke 5:39**

> "And no man drinks old wine and at once desires the new , for he says,'The old is sweet'.

Commenting on this verse Ellicott says: "new or sweet wine, drunk within a year or so of fermentation, would seem to have been the favourite delicacy".

A. Is old wine sweet? [Aramaic]

B. Is new wine sweet? [Ellicott]

C. Why does Aramaic Bible have sweet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us remind ourselves of the original Greek in Luke 5:39 (this verse has no parallel in Matthew, Mark or John):

> καὶ οὐδεὶς πιὼν παλαιὸν θέλει νέον· λέγει γάρ Ὁ παλαιὸς χρηστός ἐστιν
> = and no one having drunk old [wine] desires new; for he says, "The old is better".

Observe that "sweet" does not occur in the Greek at all.

Now, recall that the Aramaic versions are a translation of a translation.  A few such are readily available:

**Aramaic Bible in Plain English**

> And no man drinks old wine and at once desires the new, for he says,
> “The old is sweet.”

**George Lamsa Bible**

> And no man drinks old wine, and immediately wants new wine; for he
> says, The old is delicious.

**John W Etheridge (1849)**

> And no man, drinking old wine, immediately asketh new: for he saith,
> The old is softer.

**James Murdoch (1852)**

> And no one drinketh old wine, and immediately calleth for new; for he
> saith, The old is the delicious.

New Version here >> https://www.thearamaicscriptures.com/

> And no nash {man} drinks khamra athiqa {the old wine} and mekhda
> {immediately} asks for khadtha {the new}, for, he says, athiqa {the
> old} is sweet.”

This last version and the most literal and agree with the first listed above.  Thus, it appears that the literal meaning of the Aramaic word here is actually "sweeter".  The others appear to be idiomatic translations.

Comment: +1 You have answered the essence of my question. Whilst thinking about this verse and sweetness would it be appropriate to add to your answer something about the Jews finding the old covenant/wine sweeter. When in reality it is the new covenant that is sweeter?

Comment: @C.Stroud - I think the application/interpretation of this verse is a bit more involved that old vs new covenant, although that is a small part of the story.

Comment: Thanks. I have found other questions on this site which deal with the further issues.